# Moving a Java Keystore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, jks

I have a wildcard cert and a jks with my chain of trust. When I want to use the wild card on another host for SSL (another java web server), do I simply copy the jks to the other host and use? Or is the jks specific to a host and therefore should remain on the host it was created on...?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is nothing else in the Java keystore that you would want to keep on only the original server, you can copy the keystore to the other server.